# Vector subscript out of range c++ error

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

When i run the following code i get this exception vector subscript out of range, this code worked successfully without exception on an image but when i changed the image an exception occurs.

```
Mat bw;
inRange(output1, Scalar(low_h, low_s, low_v), Scalar(high_h, high_s, high_v), bw);  
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Mat dst = Mat::zeros(input_image.size(), input_image.type());

for(unsigned int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
{
    cout << "# of contour points: " << contours[i].size() << endl ;
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<contours[i].size();j++)
    {
        cout << "Point(x,y)=" << contours[i][j]<< endl;
    }
    cout << " Area: " << cv::contourArea(cv::Mat(contours[i], false)) << endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >::iterator itc= contours.begin();
    while (itc!=contours.end()) {
        if (contours[i].size()>500 || contours[i].size()<20 )
        itc= contours.erase(itc);
    else 
        ++itc;
    }
```

Comment: What's `i`? You include it in this code snippet without any reference to what it is or where it comes from. You should be using the iterator rather than direct subscript access here.

Comment: Where do you set `i`?

Comment: i is a counter to find # of contour points in an image I tried this code on an image without exception but when i change the image it gives me  vector subscript out of range exception

Comment: are you missing a closing curly brace at the end of the code? there are 2 opening backets and one closing.

Comment: no i just didn't write here

Comment: please help me I need to know how to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you erase an element from the vector `contours` it reduces the size of the vector. The index `i` goes from 0 to `contours.size() - 1`, where the `contours.size()` is computed in the outer loop. In the inner loop the size of `contours` will be reduced when you erase an element from `contours`, but `i` is not updated to reflect the reduced size of contours. That's why you get *vector subscript out of range error*.

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
{
    // something else ...

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >::iterator itc= contours.begin();
    while (itc!=contours.end()) {      
        if (contours[i].size()>500 || contours[i].size()<20 ) { 
            itc= contours.erase(itc); 
            // Now contours will have one less element
            // However index i has not been updated and so
            // contours[i] will eventually index out of range in 
            // one of the subsequent iterations of this inner loop
        }
        else {
            ++itc;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you alot it worked for images but with some images it didnt work

Comment: how did you fix the issue?

Comment: for(unsigned int i=0;i<contours[i].size();i++)
     {
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >::iterator itc= contours.begin();
    
while (itc!=contours.end()) {
  if (contours[i].size()>500 || contours[i].size()<50 )
       itc= contours.erase(itc);
   else 
       ++itc; 
}
     }

Comment: i don't understand what you've done. I just told you why the error is. You should try to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: i don't know exactly what you are doing. But if your goal is to remove contours that are too big or too small there is a more streightforward way to do so.

Comment: specifically why do you have to erase elements in the inner loop? Why can't you erase the elements in the loop of its own?

Comment: i did that " erase the elements in the loop of its own " ! but it didnt work